# Debug Heroku Spring boot apps locally?

Tags: java, debugging, heroku, remote-debugging, ngrok

My project has OAuth implementation. Thus I had to register my webapplication in salesforce to receive a callback url. 
I used to change this callback url every 7 hours as ngrok(for exposing my local url to internet) session expires after that.

But now my company has blocked ngrok sites and now it comes under restricted side.

Now I am trying to use Heroku, and have run heroku cli to run apps locally, but how do i attach debugger in my intelliJ IDE? 
Can we debug apps using Heroku CLI?